# how to shorten code involving php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery

This code is very simple so I feel like it could be shortened by relating the php variable to the jquery function parameter. if you have any ideas, please help. thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php if (is_page($toppageID1)) { ?> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    Show('1');
});
<?php } elseif (is_page($toppageID2)) { ?> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    Show('2');
});
<?php } elseif (is_page($toppageID3)) { ?> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    Show('3');
});
<?php } elseif (is_page($toppageID4)) { ?> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    Show('4');
});
<?php } elseif (is_page($toppageID5)) { ?> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    Show('5');
});
<?php } elseif (is_page($toppageID6)) { ?> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    Show('6');
});
<?php } elseif (is_page($toppageID7)) { ?> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    Show('7');
});
<?php }; ?>
</script>
```

Comment: yes, the JS code can be shortened. But you need to change your PHP code a bit. Why ot just get the last digit of your PHP variable and put it into the jquery? You'd have to change the PHP code where the vars are generated

Comment: can you give me an example of how i should create the php variable?

Comment: You should start by taking out the repeated `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` outside the PHP if block.

Comment: Ya thats true, Ates. Also Switch is the way to go.

Comment: Where are you getting the `$toppageIDX` variable? GET/POST/DB.. ? If it's via the URI there would be a better method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have something like `$somevalue` that would help to switch instead of `elseif`.

```
<script>
<?php   switch($somevalue){ ?>
$(document).ready(
    function (){
    <?php case 1:  //?>
    <?php case 2:  //?>
    <?php case 3:  //?>
    <?php case 4:  //?>
    <?php case 5:  //?>

    }
)

<?php } ?>
</script>
```

Comment: How would this work assuming the PHP toppageID variables are unique ids?

Comment: @tbranyen to be honest he's got logical error using `elseif` with different values.

Comment: <?php $currID = get_the_ID(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
<?php switch($currID) { 
    case $toppageID1: echo "Show('1')"; break;
    case $toppageID2: echo "Show('2')"; break; 
    case $toppageID3: echo "Show('3')"; break; 
    case $toppageID4: echo "Show('4')"; break; 
    case $toppageID5: echo "Show('5')"; break; 
 case $toppageID6: echo "Show('6')"; break; 
    case $toppageID7: echo "Show('7')"; break; 

 } ?>
});
</script>

Comment: @user643440 i suppose it is so

Answer (score 0):

First off I would change that function of yours `is_page` to `page` and return a string with the ID.  You already have access to those $toppageID variables in PHP so why not use them in the function itself.  If you absolutely cannot for scoping or other reasons, pass them all in the function at once.  You want a single output not executing the function numerous times.

Example script using the re-factored function `page`:

```
<body>
...

<!-- end of body -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(id) {

        if(id) {
            Show(id);
        }
        else {
            // throw some error or something
        }

    })(<?php echo page() ?>);
</script>
</body>
```

If you need to funnel all the variables at once maybe something like this:

```
})(<?php echo page($toppageID1,$toppageID2,$toppageID3,...) ?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

SOrry if I was unclear but im using wordpress functions. a switch works great.

```
<?php $currID = get_the_ID(); ?>
```

$(document).ready(function () {

});